# Handle success response when there is no Data returned by the server with Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am trying to implement Networking with Combine Framework and I am able to fetch data from server using following code but I am facing an issue when there is no data returned from the server but the request was successful.

```
   return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .tryMap { response in
         print(response)
        guard let httpURLResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200..<299 ~= httpURLResponse.statusCode  else {
           throw CustomError.serverError
         }
         if response.data.isEmpty && 200..<299 ~= httpURLResponse.statusCode {
            //HOW TO HANDLE IF if there is no Data from server but request has been processed successfully
         }
         return response.data
        }
        .decode(type: R.self, decoder: decoder)
        .mapError{CustomError.map(error: $0)}
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Can you please guide me on how to handle success response when there is no Data returned by the server.

Let me know if I have to elaborate on my question.

Comment: What do you want to happen? I don't think you mentioned that. Do you want no value being emitted and pipeline complete, do you want to emit `nil`, or do you want to fail?

Comment: ahh sorry, I did not mention. I want to return success. With the above code I am getting an error as there is no data.

Comment: What do you mean by "return success"? Your pipeline currently is expected to return a value of type `R` and a failure of `CustomError`. You could change it to return `R?` - i.e. return nil in case of success with no data to decode. Or not emit anything except completion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, Even I did try to handle optional (using R?) but I get error : "The given data was not valid JSON."

Comment: You still haven't answered - what do you want the behavior to be from the point of view of the subscriber? (Yes, just changing to `R?` isn't going to work)

Comment: ok..let me explain. I have a subscriber in my ViewModel and when the operation is successful and I want to notify the user with a success response. With the above code, I did not get any success response in Sinc. So in short, How can I detect in subscriber whether the operation is a success or failure. Hope I was able to explain. Plz let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, since you need to either return the value of type `R` or "something" in case of successful but empty data response, then you could build a pipeline that returns an optional `R?`.

You'd need to use `flatMap` to handle this branch:

```
return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .tryMap { response -> Data in
        guard let httpURLResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
           200..<299 ~= httpURLResponse.statusCode {
           throw CustomError.serverError
        }
        return response.data
    } 
    .flatMap { data -> AnyPublisher<R?, Error> in
       if data.isEmpty {
          return Just(nil).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
       }

       return Just(data).decode(type: R?.self, decoder: decoder)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .mapError {
       $0 as? CustomError ?? CustomError.map(error: $0)
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The pipeline above will return a `R?` value, and `nil` when data is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance .. Really appreciate.